# Please provide How to on how to write to specific site user in chat

Tags: support, chat, stack-exchange

In my questions I am urged to not discuss much in comments and use chat instead. I've reviewed chat FAQ https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq but there is no info on how to write to specific user.

Comment: You can't, unless the user already has a chat account in which case you can invite them to a room.

Answer (score 2):

To write to a specific user, notify them by typing "@" and then the user's username. There shouldn't be any spaces. Eg, Jon M would be notified by "@JonM" without the quotes. Then take a space and continue talking. This only works if they've been in that room sometime in the last two weeks.

Comment: That requires that they already be in the room, which is usually unlikely.

Comment: @Catija I've pinged users with them being out of the room before.

Comment: They have to have been in the room sometime in the last two weeks. Otherwise, you can't ping them.... still extremely unlikely. Only mods can ping anyone they want.

Comment: @Catija Oh, got it. Thank you.

Comment: Then reminding users of using chat is not logical.

Comment: @Link08 I think there may be some confusion here. If you @ somebody in a comment, that person will be notified of the new comment. In that way, they can be made aware of a chat room. It seems as if "notification," is also being used to discuss some kind of direct notification outside of comments. I know that you can always be "comment notified," regardless of having been in a chat room or not. I have no experience with "direct notification." (The word "ping" may have a particular meaning here.)

Comment: In this particular case I want to talk with someone after my questions was locked and all my comments removed.

Comment: @Link08 I think it should still be possible to notify them if you have the 20 rep needed to talk in chat.

Comment: only if they were in room in the last two weeks

Comment: @Link08 Then I don't think there's any way to contact them in chat.

Comment: Then reminding users of using chat by moderators is not logical.

Comment: @Link08 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "moderators." Could you please explain?

Comment: It's not critical, we can remove that "by moderators" part.

Comment: @Link08 You mean the "Chat is not for extended discussion" thing? It should be always possible to notify then, because chat rooms "freeze" or "close" after about 13-14 days of no activity, so notifiying a user in that situation wouldn't work after 2 weeks.

Comment: 1 I ask question 2 my question is down voted 3 I ask why 4 my question is locked and my comments removed and I am sad to use the chat 5 I can not use the chat

Comment: You're more than capable of writing a comment, @Link08 Asking the person you're conversing with of meeting you in [link to chat room] for further discussion. You don't *need* to ping them in chat. This has the added benefit of other users being able to find where the discussion continues.